# How to validate that at least one checkbox is checked in each set of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a large group of checkboxes that are separated by two tables. Out of the two sets of checkboxes, I want the user to be required to check at least one checkbox in both sets before submitting a form (so, based on my code, at least one checkbox under COST and one under BENEFIT). I hope this makes sense. My code is below:

```
<body>
<h2 align="center">Cost/Benefit Matrix</h2>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mytesting/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
p
    {
        font-family: "Arial";
        align: center;
    }
h2
    {
        font-family: "Arial";
    }
</style>


<p>
<table border="1" align="center">

<tbody>
<tr>
    <th><b>COST</b></th>
    <th colspan="3">Reduced Cost</th>
    <th>Neutral</th>
    <th colspan="3">Increased Cost</th>
    <th>Don't Know</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>High</th>
    <th>Medium</th>
    <th>Low</th>
    <th>No effect</th>
    <th>Low</th>
    <th>Medium</th>
    <th>High</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Capital cost</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix1" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix2" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix3" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix4" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix5" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix6" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix7" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix8" value="1"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Clinical operating cost</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix9" value="1" style="vertical-align: middle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix10" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix11" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix12" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix13" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix14" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix15" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix16" value="1"></td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Facility operating cost</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix17" value="1" style="vertical-align: middle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix18" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix19" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix20" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix21" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix22" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix23" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix24" value="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Energy cost</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix25" value="1" style="vertical-align: middle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix26" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix27" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix28" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix29" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix30" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix31" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix32" value="1"></td>
</tr>

<br>
<br>

<table border="1" align="center">

<tbody>
<tr>
    <th><b>BENEFIT</b></th>
    <th colspan="3">Negative Impact</th>
    <th>Neutral</th>
    <th colspan="3">Positive Impact</th>
    <th>Don't Know</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>High</th>
    <th>Medium</th>
    <th>Low</th>
    <th>No effect</th>
    <th>Low</th>
    <th>Medium</th>
    <th>High</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Patient/staff safety</td>

    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix33" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix34" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix35" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix36" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix37" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix38" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix39" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix40" value="1"></td>


</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Fire/life safety</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix41" value="1" style="vertical-align: middle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix42" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix43" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix44" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix45" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix46" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix47" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix48" value="1"></td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Clinical quality of care</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix49" value="1" style="vertical-align: middle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix50" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix51" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix52" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix53" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix54" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix55" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix56" value="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Patient/resident experience</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix57" value="1" style="vertical-align: middle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix58" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix59" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix60" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix61" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix62" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix63" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix64" value="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Operational efficiency</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix65" value="1" style="vertical-align: middle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix66" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix67" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix68" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix69" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix70" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix71" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix72" value="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Sustainability</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix73" value="1" style="vertical-align: middle"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix74" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix75" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix76" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix77" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix78" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix79" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix80" value="1"></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

      // uncheck sibling checkboxes (checkboxes on the same row)
      $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', false);

      // uncheck checkboxes in the same column
      $('div').find('input[type="checkbox"]:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').not(this).prop('checked', false);

    });
</script>
</tbody>
</tbody>
</p>
```

Comment: Have you considered using radiobutton?

Comment: I tried to pull your code into jsfiddle to help you out, but your mark up is... well, seemingly, all over the place. There are tags ending in odd areas and it's hard to get a handle on it.

Comment: zfrisch - try again, I had div tags when there did not need to be any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a class (like `.checkbox`) to each of your checkboxes and then perform something like this before submit -

```
if ($(".checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
    //perform submit
}
else{
    alert("check at least one checkbox!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ".is: for more readability.

```
if ( $( '.checkbox' ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
   // atleast one checked
} else {
   // none checked
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rr3vfymy/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML isn't well-formed. You should close one table element before starting a new one.

Then start by distinguishing your tables by id, or at least by class, for example:

```
<table id="cost-table" border="1" align="center">
```

and then check, if at least one is checked. If you are using jQuery, you can use something like:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    // you should use id on form too, this will bug if you have more forms on your page
    $( "form" ).submit( function( event ) {
        if( $( "#cost-table input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).length === 0 ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //alert user here
            alert('You need to select at least one cost type');
        }
    });
});
```

and the same for other types.